# MATLAB TODO: Fill in Description

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I was trying to find something about `LegendEntry` in MATLAB, so I clicked it to open the help window, and this is what I saw:

[image: MATLAB todo]

If you want to see it yourself run this code:

```
h = plot(1:10,1:10);
legend('a')
h.Annotation.LegendInformation
```

Then you will see at the command window:

```
ans = 
  LegendEntry with properties:

    IconDisplayStyle: 'on'
```

`LegendEntry` is a link to the help file for `matlab.graphics.eventdata.LegendEntry` which pops up the window in the picture above.

Are you familiar with this? Is this some kind of a problem with my installation?

I use MATLAB 2015a.

Comment: There's just no help written for that. What are you trying to learn about it? You can use `meta.class.fromName('matlab.graphics.eventdata.LegendEntry')` to learn more about this object.

Comment: Well, usually it says "No help found for..."
I was trying to figure out what is this object in a figure

Comment: It does say "No help found for..." in 2015b. Someone was probably just lazy to put in a description, and then forgot to remove TODO before release.

Comment: I can confirm "doc matlab.graphics.eventdata.legendentry" produces the same window in my R2015a installation. It's not an installation problem. It's just missing documentation.

Comment: So that's just some kind of funny lacuna in the help file ;)

Comment: It's not an error, it's an Easter egg ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happened here is that a developer has left a TODO note to him or herself in the comments for `matlab.graphics.eventdata.LegendEntry`, and has forgotten to remove it before release.

If you'd noticed this in the most recent release, it would probably be worth bringing it to the notice of MathWorks with a bug report: but in fact I've just tried this on 16a and it looks like it's been removed already.

It's not a problem with your installation.